Remove Drepracated \Zend_Pdf in magento 2
I have upgraded my magento versio to 2.4.6-p1.
I need to change the Zend with Luminas.
In my file I am having the following line
 $this->pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();

How do i change this Zend to support magento version 2.4.6
Replacement for Zend

The package ZendPdf is deprecated and has not been migrated to Laminas (see official repository)
As suggested in the readme, you'll need to switch to another implementation, such as tcpdf or mpdf. 
There's no migration guide for them.
